# ASP.NET/entityframework не получается изменить Timeout для с помощью SetCommandTimeout

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

с толкнулся со следующей проблемой: требуется помещать в MS Server большое количество строк (100000+). Для добавления использую следующий код:

```
 public void AddRange(List<Record> list, WindowsIdentity user)
    {
        if (list != null)
        {
            WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated(user.AccessToken, () =>
           {

               using (var context = new RecordContext())
               {
                   context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(300);
                   context.tblGoodsSupplierPermissionRuleBuffer.AddRange(list);
                   context.SaveChanges();
               }
           });
        }
    }
```

В конструкторе так же указал:

```
  public RecordContext()
    {
        this.Database.SetCommandTimeout(300);
    }
```

И даже в Startup.cs

```
services.AddDbContext<RecordContext>(
            options =>options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RecordContext"), 
            sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(300)));
```

Однако при выполнении запроса ровно через 2 минуты каждый раз получаю следующее сообщение:
[image: Снимок экрана ошибки]

С маленьким количеством данных все отрабатывает хорошо.
В чем может быть причина подобного поведения?

Comment: измените атрибут `requestTimeout` в web.config тег `aspNetCore`,, у него по умолчанию стоит 2 минуты.

Comment: Для помещения в БД реально большого количества данных существует BulkInsert. Можно сколько угодно выжимать кошку, простите, EF, но до скорости bulk-операций его не дотянуть ни какими шаманствами. Но вы можете пытаться и дальше, мешать не буду.

Comment: @Ruslan_K, спасибо, действительно дело в этом. Правда сначала придется создать web.config, т.к. почему то в ASP NET .core 2+ по умолчанию данный файл отсутствует.

Comment: @rdorn. Спасибо за совет. Я слышал про BulkInsert, и о его возможностях по вставке большого  количества строк. 1) Я правильно понимаю,, что EF не предоставляет BulkInsert? 2) Можете подробней рассказать, как конкретно мне выполнять вставку большого количества строк (т.е. мне стоит вовсе отказаться от фреймворков?)

Comment: EF не предоставляет, он не для этого. Отказываться - дело ваше, я не знаю какие задачи должно решать ваше приложение. Что-то можно оставить на EF, что-то сделать иначе. Каждому инструменту свои задачи и каждой задаче подходящий инструмент. А вставка там тривиальная - заполняете DataTable  и передаете в качестве параметра, но нюансы конечно есть, попробуйте, если что-то будет непонятно разберемся.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/extensions/#efcorebulkextensions теперь видимо предоставляет, но этим я еще не пользовался